# homebrew install dependencies if unmet

Tags: ruby, macos, dependencies, homebrew, dependency-management

I have a [brew](https://brew.sh/) package setup through [GitHub](https://github.com): [diagnosticator](https://github.com/cccnrc/homebrew-diagnosticator)

This is a simple [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) file ([diagnosticator.rb](https://github.com/cccnrc/homebrew-diagnosticator/blob/main/diagnosticator.rb)) that points to the actual hosting repository: [diagnosticator-mac](https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac) and provides instructions on how to install files:

```rb
class Diagnosticator < Formula
  desc "Diagnosticator Mac OS homebrew package"
  homepage "https://diagnosticator.com"
  url "https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/archive/refs/tags/v0.1.11.tar.gz"
  sha256 "f36987ce96c7be269da12b9dce8186c5245aef4046fe62173a145024b5e88b98"
  license "MIT"

  depends_on "docker"
  depends_on "docker-compose"
  depends_on "wget"
  depends_on "jq"

  def install
    bin.install "diagnosticator"
    bin.install "diagnosticator-mac.sh"
    bin.install Dir["files"]
    prefix.install "README.md"
  end
end
```

How can I tell [brew](https://brew.sh/) to automatically install dependencies ([docker](https://www.docker.com/), [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) if they are unmet in the machine that is installing diagnosticator?

---

If you want to try it:

```sh
brew install cccnrc/diagnosticator/diagnosticator
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused so I am probably missing something. Does it not already do that?

Answer (score 0):

This might be something that you are looking for.

Setup the formula file as below

```
cat << EOF > ./formula/diagnosticator.rb
class Diagnosticator < Formula
  desc "Diagnosticator Mac OS homebrew package"
  homepage "https://diagnosticator.com"
  url "https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac/archive/refs/tags/v0.1.11.tar.gz"
  sha256 "f36987ce96c7be269da12b9dce8186c5245aef4046fe62173a145024b5e88b98"
  license "MIT"

  depends_on "docker"
  depends_on "docker-compose"
  depends_on "wget"
  depends_on "jq"

  def install
    bin.install "diagnosticator"
    bin.install "diagnosticator-mac.sh"
    bin.install Dir["files"]
    prefix.install "README.md"
  end
end
EOF
```

And then run `brew info diagnosticator`

```
$ brew info diagnosticator
diagnosticator: stable 0.1.11
Diagnosticator Mac OS homebrew package
https://diagnosticator.com
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/diagnosticator.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Required: docker ✘, docker-compose ✘, wget ✘, jq ✔
```

Let me know if that works.